# The name 'myText' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i just start learning to use Unity. and i got this error message : The name 'myText' does not exist in the current context. Can you guys help me?

```
void Update(){
    Debug.Log(myText)
}
```

[Check the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vBvz.png)

Comment: Because there *isn't* `myText`, as the compiler says. We need more context. Could you please edit your question, to include more information about your situation?

Comment: You need to learn about [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/). Basically your `Update` method can only "see" variables defined in its own body or its own class. There is no `myText` in the  body, so it should be in the class scope, which apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but if the compiler says `myText` is not in the context, then literally you didn't declared variable `myText`.

Maybe there is typo, no local variable, no field declared... but since you've included the picture of inspector, I assume that you want to serialize a string field, and print it on every `Update()` call.

So try this on your code:

```cs
[SerializeField]
private string myText;
```

Doing so will expose `myText` value on inspector, then you can modify serialized value on the inspector.